# Rails/Postgres: Strategy to save Historical Prices of 1000 CryptoCurrencies on Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, dataset, price

I want to save and display Historical Prices of 2500 CryptoCurrencies. Wich is the best strategy to save all that data on my database? I think is not a good idea create 2500 Tables with a row for every price...

Database: Postgres

Thank you very much

Comment: Do the attributes of a Historical Price vary from CryptoCurrency to CryptoCurrency? That is, does a Historical Price for CryptoCurrencyA have different attributes than a Historical Prices for CryptoCurrencyB? Or, do the Historical Prices all have the same attributes regardless of CryptoCurrency? If they vary, by how much?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very broad question, but most likely a star schema would help you setting this up in a flexible and scalable way.

I can envisage this as a very simple setup with a fact table holding the historical data about prices by a timestamp, and a couple of dimension tables holding informations about the coins (i.e exchange rates, merchants) etc.

This is a simple guide about [star schema](https://www.guru99.com/star-snowflake-data-warehousing.html)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB could be an good option. Create for each currency one collection. Take care to do not load to big collections at once, rather create a aggregated collection.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot to say that I'm using Postgres...

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion questions like this don't seem "too broad".

You can always create a table and have it partitioned by year, possibly crypto code if you have lots of price points.

I personally am a fan of denormalized data models but if you are thinking of storing the crypto code in a separate table and the price points in another there may be some small advantage in terms of query time - indexing the price points table based on an integer (crypto_id) may result in faster queries.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html